# Joomla 3 server-registered users passwords left empty

Tags: security, authentication, joomla, ldap

I am on Joomla 3.9 and just enabled LDAP authentication plugin. New users who log in successfully are automatically registered (a new user is created) by Joomla. And they continue to be able to login by their LDAP credentials.

My question is for those users their password field in database table #__users are left empty. I verified that they are NOT able to login with empty password, because Joomla does not even let users try to login with empty password.

First question: I am concerned if password field being empty does it open window for malicious attempts?

Second question:
If the users click "Forgot Password" they are able to initialize a Joomla user password. If they do they would be able to login by EITHER, actually BOTH Joomla password and LDAP passwords. How should this be handled? (My LDAP server is provided by an online LDAP identity provider.)

Thank you for helping.

Comment: IMHO you better ask not programming related Joomla questions on https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry for bother.

Comment: All Joomla-related questions are on-topic at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.